# Do I necessarily need a third party framework for a Java-based REST service (JSON)?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, rest, jax-rs

Of course JAX-RS should work without any additional framework like JAX-WS also does. 
But in JAX-WS, I just put some annotations on a POJO, create a self hosted service with one single line of code and that's it.

I can't find any tutorials or resources that show how to do the same with JAX-RS. Nearly every tutorial uses Jersey (or Easyrest etc.) and at least Maven. Isn't there an easy way to set up a Rest based service like it can be done with JAX-WS?

Thank you

edit: Hm, I think annotations like @Path etc. aren't available without these frameworks? My eclipse cannot reference/find them :(

Comment: REST web services are easy to do by hand, I guess there is little space between that and a framework based solution. Still, there is nothing wrong with using a simple framework (don't reivent the wheel etc.); Maven is definitely not necessary, they probably just use it in the examples to keep setup simple.

Comment: more close answer to the question :

[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913866/creating-a-restful-webservice-without-using-jersey-or-any-other-libs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JAX-RS is an API. Jersey and RESTEasy are its implementations. Jersey, is the 'reference' implementation of JAX-RS, and therefore shows up frequently in tutorials (after all, one needs *some* implementation of the API to use it).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services

Answer (score -2):

Restful webservices can be easily accessed. You can even use:

`URL url = new URL(docUrl);
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();`

you can use the connection just like using it anywhere else.