# Creating a RESTful WebService without using Jersey or any other libs

Tags: jax-rs

okay you might say its a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207632/do-i-necessarily-need-a-third-party-framework-for-a-java-based-rest-service-jso).

It might be but the answer is still yet to be found.

Isn't there any way we can make a RESTful web service without using jersey or for that matter any other libs?

I am searching for the past 5 days for the answer to this question!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with servlets. 
Create a servlet for each service or url that you expose to your service consumers.

Eg. For a user CRUD service, create a UserServlet and specify the mapping as /user/*.
Consumers of your service, will hit urls such as

- http://yourdomain.com/user
- http://yourdomain.com/user/23

for various RESTful operations.

Inside of the servlet, you should be able to extract the request parameters, form data, request headers and context information.

For a detailed discussion on how to design your restful api and best practices, search "Restful API Design". Here are a couple of links to get you started

- https://blog.apigee.com/detail/api_design_third_edition_video_slides
- https://blog.apigee.com/detail/slides_for_restful_api_design_second_edition_webinar/

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use JAX-RS, which is a specification, you must use an implementation of this specification. Jersey is the Reference Implementation of JAX-RS but any other implementation is fine, too.

You can write a service with a RESTFul interface using plain Servlets. But why reinvent the wheel? You really don't want to do this. But if you must, read [the Java EE Tutorial on Servlets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html). But a Servlet will not be RESTFul without further work. You can easily fall into the trap of writing a RPC-style service.

Comment: but cant we use a plain jax-rs implmentation instead of using jersey ?

Comment: meaning no importing of extern libs in the project !

Comment: I've edited my answer (again). Could you please explain, *why* you want to do this?

Comment: well i cant import extern libs in my eclipse project and my project is to build a restful web service !!

Comment: Then why don't you fix this importing problem?

Comment: there is no importing problem there is an importing restriction :(
Also isnt it good to move on from basics (just a thought being optimistic about my situation) !

Comment: which tutorial..i know the basics of servlets.. but not of JAX-RS implementation !!